# Selecting database generated value from a drop-down list?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Messing with some code from W3 schools with PHP and Ajax. I've got a database that I am pulling last names from. I want to be able to store that last name in a variable and print it out at the bottom of the page. Since the names are dynamically created from the database, there is no "value" to reference to capture the variable that way.

The code works by the user beginning to type a name into the textbox, and the AJAX function autocompletes. If the user selects a name as the one they were searching for, how do I capture that as a variable?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

//Ajax tutorial - http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/
function showHint(str)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length==0){ 
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
      return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else{// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      { 
         document.getElementById("browsers").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getName.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<?php

    $msg = "";
    $name = "";
    $test = "Test.";
         if (isset($_POST['enter'])) //check if this page is requested after Submit button is clicked
         {  

            $name = trim($_POST['']);//What do I need to select here?!? 
         }
?>

</head>
<body>
<h3>Start typing a name in the input field below:</h3>
<form action="3-searchName.php"> 
Search by Last Name: 
<!--
<select name="drop" onchange="showHint(this.value)">
<option value = "">Enter last name here</option>
</select>
-->

<input type="text" list="browsers" name="drop" value="" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" />
<datalist id="browsers" >

</datalist>
<input name="enter" class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<br/><br/>
User information will show here when the button is clicked.
<br/>
<?php echo $name ;?>
<br/>
<?php echo $test ;?>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: $name = trim($_POST['drop']); And you need to have form method as post

Comment: @RavinderReddy Appreciate it! That did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onblur action on the text input.  The assumption is that when the user leaves the input they have found the name they want.  Then you can grab the value and use it however you want.  You can also verify the selection via ajax if you wanted to be sure it is a valid database selection.  Using the select does some of this for you by the onchange action and the dropdown is populated from the select.